# AsyncHttpClient and Netty - hook for worker thread being returned to pool?

Tags: java, netty, asynchttpclient

I'm using AsyncHttpClient along with Netty to perform non-blocking REST calls between microservices. I'm trying to figure out how to clear out threadLocal values once the Netty worker thread is returned to the pool.

In my AsyncCompletionHandler onCompleted() and onThrowable() methods (i.e. when the HTTP response is returned) I add some threadLocal data. Specifically, I store an ID associated with the request chain to help correlate log messages between services. Once the worker thread is done executing and is returned to the thread pool, I need to clear this threadLocal data out. However, I can't find any hooks for this.

I thought that creating my own ExecutorService that overrides afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) and setting it via my AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder would work, but I think I'm misunderstanding how AsyncHttpClient uses the ExecutorService. Neither beforeExecute(), execute(), or afterExecute() is called at all in the process of sending/receiving HTTP requests/responses, only when the ExecutorService is first created.

So, is there any way for me to know when a worker thread is done executing and is to be returned to the threadPool?

For the record, here are the libraries I'm using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ning</groupId>
    <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.31</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.32.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your AHC and Netty versions are not aligned. AHC1 targets Netty 3 while AHC2 targets Netty 4.

Then, don't try to do that. Threads are not returned to the pool

Threads are associated with multiple sockets at the same time and responses can be spanned over multiple TCP frames.

Comment: Thanks for the info on AHC and Netty versions. Bummer on the threading behavior; it sounds like using threadlocal data is a bad idea once I've received an async http response. Is this basically true of NIO in general?

Comment: Well, generally speaking, using ThreadLocals for storing long lived data just so that you don't have to pass it as method parameters, is a bad idea. It only works if you have a sequential one thread path. Non blocking APIs provide you with callbacks where you would store such data, see AHC's AsyncHandler and ListenableFuture.

Comment: I agree that using ThreadLocals is a suboptimal solution; I'm stuck with trying to make our existing frameworks work with async calls. But it definitely helps to know the limits of this approach.